# SideMenu Jonkykong sideMenuDidAppear and sideMenuDidDisappear delegate not firing

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm trying to apply [Jonkykong-SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) in my project with QR scanner and the Pulley library as well, the result is fine, the SideMenu could slide in and slide out, but I couldn't get the delegate for `sideMenuDidAppear` and `sideMenuDidDisappear` to fire. I need those to start and stop the capture session.

**My Storyboard:**

[image]

In my `ProductScanPageViewController` (Main View Controller), I put the extension below:

```
extension ProductScanPageViewController: SideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate {

    func sideMenuDidAppear(menu: SideMenuNavigationController, animated: Bool) {
        print("sidemenudidappear")
        stopCaptureSession()
    }

    func sideMenuDidDisappear(menu: SideMenuNavigationController, animated: Bool) {
        startCaptureSession()
    }
}
```

and the print result didn’t appear in the console when I slide out the SideMenu. Do I have to put the SideMenu in the PulleyViewController instead? The initial ViewController in the storyboard is already used by Pulley.

I might modify one of the frameworks as last resort, but I'm trying to avoid that, any help?

Comment: 1. You are saying you put the extension on ProductScanViewController, but it shows as ProductScanPageViewController.
2. Have you set the delegate properly?

Comment: 1. Mistyped, it was ProductScanPageViewController, I'm going to correct it in the post, 2. Apparently I missed a line in my code, sideMenuNavigationController.sideMenuDelegate = self under the segue prepare, it is now fixed, sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

Setting `sideMenuNavigationController.sideMenuDelegate = self` after preparing for segue solves the problem

Comment: If you use pan gesture you must set delegate as well when setting up gesture. Otherwise first time when swiping, prepare() function is not called.